# Mocking with argument returns wrong result

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, xunit

I need to test a method which accepts a `string` argument called `division`. I created a mock repository. I have 3 objects in this repo: 2 of them with `Division="NYC"` and 1 with `Division="LAX"`. I passed argument "NYC" to my mock and what I wanted to get in return is 2 objects (I used `Count` method of `Shouldly` to assert it). Unfortunately, I get an error that there should be 2 but were 3 objects. What's important whene I call Hanndler method agains db then I return 2 objects. Is there anything wrong with argument passing?

```
    // interface to mock
    public interface IUserRepository<UserDto>
    {
        Task<IReadOnlyList<UserDto>> ListAllActiveUsers(string division);
    }

    // Request
    public class GetUserListQuery : IRequest<List<UserListVm>>
    {
        public string Division { get; set; }
    }

    // Request Handler
    public class GetUserListQueryHandler : IRequestHandler<GetUserListQuery, List<UserListVm>>
    {
        //private readonly IAsyncRepository<UserDto> _asyncRepository;
        private readonly IUserRepository<UserDto> _userRepository;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public GetUserListQueryHandler(IUserRepository<UserDto> userRepository, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _userRepository = userRepository;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }


        public async Task<List<UserListVm>> Handle(GetUserListQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var allUsers = (await _userRepository.ListAllActiveUsers(request.Division)).OrderBy(o => o.Id);
            return _mapper.Map<List<UserListVm>>(allUsers);
        }
    }


    // Repository mock
    public class UserRepositoryMocks
    {
        public static Mock<IUserRepository<UserDto>> GetUserRepository()
        {
            var users = new List<UserDto>
            {
                new UserDto
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    UserName = "Mike Smith",
                    Division = "NYC",
                    IsActive = true
                }, 
                
                new UserDto
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    UserName = "Rob Michael",
                    Division = "NYC",
                    IsActive = true
                },   
                
                new UserDto
                {
                    Id = 5,
                    UserName = "Carl Jackson",
                    Division = "LAX",
                    IsActive = true
                }
            };


            // Arrange
            var mockUserRepository = new Mock<IUserRepository<UserDto>>();

            mockUserRepository.Setup(repo => repo.ListAllActiveUsers(It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(users);

            return mockUserRepository;
        }
    }



    // xUnit test
    public class GetUserListQueryHandlerTests
    {
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        private readonly Mock<IUserRepository<UserDto>> _mockUserRepository;

        public GetUserListQueryHandlerTests()
        {
            _mockUserRepository = UserRepositoryMocks.GetUserRepository();

            var configProvider = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddProfile<MappingProfile>();
                
            });

            _mapper = configProvider.CreateMapper();
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task GetUsersListTest()
        {
            // Arrange
            var handler = new GetUserListQueryHandler(_mockUserRepository.Object, _mapper);

            // Act
            var result = await handler.Handle(new GetUserListQuery() { Division = "NYC" }, CancellationToken.None);

            // Assert
            result.ShouldBeOfType<List<UserListVm>>();
            result.Count.ShouldBe(2);
        }
    }
```

EDIT: I add a class which is implementation of interface `IUserRepository<UserDto>`, specifically its method `ListAllActiveUsers(string division)`. This implementation retrieve data against database. It works fine on real data:

```
        public async Task<IReadOnlyList<UserDto>> ListAllActiveUsers(string division)
        {
            var dbDataUsers = new List<User>();

            if (division != null)
            {
            dbDataUsers = await _dbContext.Users
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Where(x => x.IsActive == true && x.Division == division)
                .ToListAsync();
            }
            else
            {
            dbDataUsers = await _dbContext.Users
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Where(x => x.IsActive == true)
                .ToListAsync();
            }

            return _mapper.Map<List<UserDto>>(dbDataUsers);
        }
```

Comment: What is your query handler doing in this?  Your mock returns 3 objects, is your handler supposed to be performing the filtering?

Comment: I added query handler. When I call handler agains db so on real data then I return 2 objects and it all works fine.

Comment: All the query handler does is passes the division through and sorts the return.  Why are you trying to assert a specific count in your unit test?   It seems like you're mixing unit test concerns of both classes.

Comment: I just wanted to return 2 objects from mock repositry given argument `division`, just to test if passing argument works fine. Yes, handler does not do anything besides accepting an argument which filters result. And this is what I wanted to test.

Comment: Then you should customize your mock setup call for receiving a specific division and not re-use a generic mock setup.

Comment: I tried doing it. I did: `mockUserRepository.Setup(repo => repo.ListAllActiveUsers("NYC").ReturnsAsync(users);` but then I get error `System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')`. How and where should I pass this parameter correctly?

Comment: The setup looks right,  I'm not really able to tell you much about the exception without more details.  I'd recommend digging into the stack trace and stepping through the code to see where that is being thrown.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your mock is this line:

```
mockUserRepository
  .Setup(repo => repo.ListAllActiveUsers(It.IsAny<string>()))
  .ReturnsAsync(users);
```

It is simply returning a list of `users` regardless of the input parameter.

A better mock would be to specify what the parameter is supposed to be:

```
mockUserRepository
  .Setup(repo => repo.ListAllActiveUsers("NYC"))  // narrow the call to just "NYC"
  .ReturnsAsync(users.Where(x => x.Division == "NYC")); // filter out irrelevant data
```

Comment: I applied those changes, then I got an error: `'ISetup<IUserRepository<UserDto>, Task<IReadOnlyList<UserDto>>>' doesn not contain a definition for 'ReturnsAsync' and the best extension method overload 'SequenceExtensions.ReturnsAsync<IEnumerable<UserDto>>(ISetupSequentialResult<Task<IEnumerable<UserDto>>>, IEnumerable<UserDto>)' requires a receiver of type 'ISetupSequentialResult<Task<IEnumerable<UserDto>>>'`. There is some convertion problem after adding `.Where()` method . I added interface implementation (to my original post above) which retrieves data against db. Maybe here is a problem?

Comment: Do a `.ToList()` at the end of the where clause. Wanna say a list is compatible with `IReadOnlyList` type in C#.

Comment: I added it to the end of where clause. The error: `System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')`. All values are passed as arguments. Sorry for bothering you but I still don't know where the problem lies.

Comment: Oh, I would chase it via a debugger. Apparently it's saying the `users` list is actually null but it's hard to tell.

Comment: It's strange since I populated mock repo with data but you must be right.